# XML namespaces for SQL queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xml-namespaces

I would like to query the lists that are downloadable from the [OFAC downloads](https://www.treasury.gov/ofac/downloads) website in XML format, using Microsoft SQL Server statements but I cannot get the namespace declaration correct. My query below works if I remove the namespaces from the file, but I would prefer to not edit the file before querying.

Name namespace declaration (1st line) in the file is `<Sanctions xmlns="http://www.un.org/sanctions/1.0" Version="3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.un.org/sanctions/1.0 http://www.treasury.gov/ofac/downloads/sanctions/1.0/sdn_advanced.xsd">`

My query is

```
DECLARE @sanctions XML;
WITH XMLNAMESPACES ( Need namespaces here   )
SELECT @sanctions = CONVERT (XML, XmlDoc)
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\temp\sdn_advanced.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS tab(XmlDoc);

SELECT  @sanctions.query(N'/Sanctions/SanctionsEntries/SanctionsEntry') AS [Sanctions]
```

Any help would be appreciated as I have very little experience with this and I have googled myself silly

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is product specific.)

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server, edited the post, thanks